# How to assign TestNG test results to use cases?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, testng, test-reporting

I need to assign my test results to use cases.
Currently I have TestNG tests for my classes (unit tests).
Obviously those tests are classes exist because of use cases, but there is no obvious 1-1 mapping.

Is it possible to configure TestNG reports to include custom groups in reporting?

Like

**F02UC01 parse input**
for this use case I have test classes:

- *com.company.product.input.ParseTest*

**F03UC02 produce output**
for this use case I have test

- *com.company.product.input.OutputTest*
  *com.company.product.input.AnotherOutputTest*

Ideally, I do not want to rerun or rewrite existing tests. I just want another test report, with diffrent grouping criterias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you do this by creating a suite xml file. E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Use Case Tests">

  <test name="F02UC01 parse input">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.company.product.input.ParseTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="F03UC02 produce output">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.company.product.input.OutputTest"/>
      <class name="com.company.product.input.AnotherOutputTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>
```

Maybe you can select them by packages instead of classes.

```
<packages>
  <package name="com.company.product.input.*"/>
</packages>
```

You can also mix `classes` and `packages` selection. See the [testng documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml).

**EDIT**

> I am running all tests anyway. I just want another report, where some of the tests are use cases.

I guess in this case you have to implement your own [`IReporter`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters).

I would create an annotation that I can add to test methods to logically group them. E.g.

```
@Test
@TestTag("F02UC01 parse input")
public void someTest(){
}
```

and then use the [`IAnnotationFinder`](http://testng.org/javadocs/index.html?org/testng/IAnnotationTransformer.html) in my custom reporter to report tests grouped by the annotation's value.

Comment: Looks good! In this scenario, is it possible to avoid re-running tests just for sake of this report? I am running all tests anyway. I just want another report, where some of the tests are use cases.